# Layer an HTML button on top of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

The backstory is that I want to create a Google Chrome extension, and when it is active it creates a button on top of a website the user is currently on. I have looked at iframe, but Google Chrome does not allow iframe to load an html file. Any new ideas or alternate ways shared would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in index.html file google chrome extension.
After adding, It will automatically activate and appear on the webpage.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ext-toggle-btn">
  <span>Extension name</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ext-toggle-btn {
    background-color: rgb(242, 245, 247);
    box-shadow: rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.11) 2px 0px 5px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 94px;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left:-5px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 1000000001;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: rgb(224, 228, 231) rgb(224, 228, 231) rgb(224, 228, 231);
    border-image: initial;
    border-left: none;
    padding: 6px;
    transition: right 0.25s ease-in 0.2s, opacity 0.35s ease-in 0.2s;
}

.ext-toggle-btn > span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: -1px;
    line-height: 14px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

**Github example link:** https://github.com/vaibhavbhuva/simple-youtube-google-extension.git

Comment: Hi Vaibhav I am a beginner in creating Google Chrome extensions. By adding, I assume in the manifest.json, but how?

Comment: @Chris You need to reference it in the manifest.json file:
`"page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }`

For more information: 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted




https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/creating-your-first-chrome-extension-78666e4a93db

Comment: Just tested it out, and I guess I was not clear in explaining my problem. As an example, if the user is watching a YouTube video, there is a "Subscribe", "Like", and "Share" button; when the Chrome extension is active, it will add a button next to the "Subscribe" button, thus an HTML button on top of a website. Btw, great article you linked!

Comment: @Chris I have created a simple youtube google extension. Please check the link: https://github.com/vaibhavbhuva/simple-youtube-google-extension.git.

Comment: I have so questions on how you did it...but thank you!

Comment: @Chris Yes, Thanks for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If you have any questions then please ask for it.

Comment: I am curious on how the extension knows when to add the button? Like, why is there not a button on YouTube's home page?

Comment: The manifest.json is what Google reads in order to configure your extension (among others). Content scripts are files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they are able to read details of the web pages the browser visits, make changes to them and pass information to their parent extension.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Answer (score 0):

With appropriate extension permissions, you should be able to insert HTML and CSS into the active tab. You can insert a div in the beginning of the document and position it in CSS with `position:fixed|absolute`, and that should have the div overlaying the webpage content. 
You essentially want to insert your modal HTML and CSS into the active tab.

Please let me know if I understood your question. I would have left this as a comment but I don't have those account permissions yet lol.